# Looking for flight info from April 2020 through Frontier

Tags: usa, air-travel

I am trying to find flight details regarding flight #1044 through Frontier Airlines that would have taken off 4/28/2020. Frontier's website only goes back 3 days. Is there another *free* site where I can view those flight details?

Thank you!

Comment: What kind of flight details you want to find?

Comment: @Jasmine The linked duplicate doesn't include any free services, but this sort of question comes up regularly here - I'm sure someone would have identified one if it were available.